# Ruby function faster than grep

Tags: ruby, bash, grep

I was recently testing out a small Ruby script to output lines containing a specific matching pattern in a large g-zipped file when I decided that I wanted to compare the speed of (zf)grep to my script.  I may be oversimplifying something but from what I can tell, my script appears to be running exponentially faster than the similar grep function.

I am working with approximately 800 MB g-zipped XML files and my typical grep function looks like this:

```
zfgrep "expression-to-match" file_name.xml.gz
```

I am looking for a specific string value that only occurs once in the file and this generally takes about 6-7 minutes to finish on my Mid-2010 MacBook Pro.  I am comparing to this script:

```
require 'zlib'

expr, file = ARGV[0], ARGV[1]

Zlib::GzipReader.open(file) { |gz| 
    gz.each { |line| 
        puts line if line[expr] 
    } 
}
```

I am using a similar syntax to run the script:

```
ruby script.rb "expression-to-match" file_name.xml.gz
```

The Ruby script runs in about 40-50 seconds.  I don't have a great understanding of runtime optimization so I was wondering why the Ruby process is so much faster on my machine.  Obviously, it isn't nearly as flexible as grep in terms of the options there are to use with it but for what I'm doing, I don't really need that flexibility.

Comment: Have you tried separating the decompression and matching part? E.g. `time zcat file_name.xml.gz > file_name.xml; time grep "expression-to-match" file_name.xml`

Comment: I have tried this.  It doesn't seem to speed up the grep function.  Grep total time is 7m32s and Ruby is 36s.

Comment: Have you tried using a different version of grep? GNU grep maybe? Or egrep or something? My intuition is that it should be pretty fast, maybe even using a DFA if the pattern is simple enough. What is the regex you are using? Also, can you maybe provide the XML file or some other file that we can use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is that 800MB uncompressed?

Comment: It could be the difference between finding a _string_ vs finding a [regexp] _pattern_...

Comment: @UriAgassi, the ruby syntax `line[expr]` *will* do regexp matching for `expr` in `line`.

Comment: @glennjackman But `ARGV[0]` will never be a regex, it will always be a string.

Comment: @Phrogz, you are quite right: `ruby -e 'expr="[aeiou]"; line="I have a vowel"; puts "yes1" if line[expr]; puts "yes2" if line.match(expr)'`. Colin, your ruby script is not working as hard as grep is.

Comment: On my GNU+Linux system, zfgrep is much faster, even though it requires 3-4 times the syscalls (ruby: 1m26s, zfgrep: 0m12s).

Comment: @pgl It is 800 MB compressed.  

NiklasB. Unfortunately I'm unable to provide the file as it is confidential.  

glennjackman I assumed this was the case but it still seems strange that the grep is that slow.  

thatotherguy That's odd...it seems to be working the opposite way for you.  I'm a bit confused as to what may be going on with my grep.  I'm going to compare this with my GNU Linux box and see if I get similar results.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments above, your script is not doing a regular expression test, but a simple substring search.

You would need to change your script to something like this to test similar capabilities:

```
expr, file = Regexp.new(ARGV[0]), ARGV[1]
```